# Why can't Xamarin.Mac be found by Visual Studio 2019?

Tags: windows-10, visual-studio-2019, xamarin.mac

I am using VS 2019 (up to date as of 4/13/2021) on Windows 10 ( also up to date ).  When I build the Mac version of the solution I have a problem, although the UWP, iOS and Android versions build and run fine.  For Mac, the actual build is ok, but when I launch the app I immediately get a warning that Xamarin.Mac is not found and poof-bang.  In the Mac references, I see that Xamarin.Mac is present, and it's path property matches the actual file location.  I can drill down in the file system and actually see Xamarin.mac.dll.  I am stumped.

For background, I am paired up to my Mac, and the connection to the Mac appears to be fine.  I do have Visual Studio for Mac installed on the Mac, but I can't imagine how that might be messing things up.

Comment: your best bet is to post a github issue, url here: https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-macios

Comment: Thanks for the heads-up.  A similar issue regarding .net6 and iOS is already posted there.  I'll keep an eye on that.

Comment: @gem4511 You are building the macOS app on the Mac itself, correct?

Comment: Thank you for your reply.  I'm using VS on a Windows 10 machine and building the Mac version of the app using a paired Mac to build.  Yes, I have actually built the same app directly on the Mac successfully, but want to use the Windows machine in the future.  ( All software on both machines is fully up-to-date. )

Comment: If have decided to use a Mac to build MacOs and iOS versions of the app, thus avoiding any issues encountered by attempting to build them on Windows with a paired Mac.